# Move build script vNext TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a build script that I want to move to another project.  Or another server for that matter.  I would hate to recreate all the steps in the script by hand, set the variables etc.  The script is available as json under the history tab.  How can I move the build script to another project ?  I can't find any import in the history tab or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to use the REST API to get the build definition you wish to copy and take that XML to create a new definition.

https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/build/definitions